# Unable to add data to Firebase Realtime Database from the app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I trying to practice on tutorial that uses Firebase Authentication, Realtime Database, and Storage, I have come a very long way in this exercise until this problem, I successfully stores the emails and passwords on authentication and it shows on firebase console but the problem is with database, it's supposed to store the following HashMap on it, but nothing showing up on firebase Realtime console

[image]

[image]

**The rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

**Login Class**

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_login) {

    private var _binding: FragmentLoginBinding? = null
    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        if(firebaseUser != null){
            val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToMainFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

        binding.apply {
            btnlogin.setOnClickListener {
                loginUser()
            }

            textViewSignUp.setOnClickListener {
                val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragment2ToRegisterFragment2()
                findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
        }




    }

    private fun loginUser() {
        val email: String = binding.inputEmail.text.toString()
        val password: String = binding.inputPassword.text.toString()

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)
        ) {
            binding.apply {
                inputEmail.error = "Email cannot be empty"
                inputPassword.error = "Password cannot be empty"
            }

        }else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener{ task->

                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToMainFragment()
                    findNavController().navigate(action)

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error ${task.exception?.message.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Registration Class**

```
class RegisterFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_register) {
    private var _binding: FragmentRegisterBinding? = null
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var refUsers: DatabaseReference

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentRegisterBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.apply {
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener {
                registerUser()
            }

            alreadyHaveAccount.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(RegisterFragmentDirections.actionRegisterFragment2ToLoginFragment2())
            }


        }


    }

    private fun registerUser() {
        val userName: String = binding.inputUsername.text.toString()
        val email: String = binding.inputEmail.text.toString()
        val password: String = binding.inputPassword.text.toString()
        val confirmedPassword: String = binding.inputConformPassword.text.toString()

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(email)
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmedPassword)
        ) {
            binding.apply {
                inputUsername.error = "Username cannot be empty"
                inputEmail.error = "Email cannot be empty"
                inputPassword.error = "Password cannot be empty"
                inputConformPassword.error = "Confirmed password cannot be empty"
            }
        } else if (!password.equals(confirmedPassword, ignoreCase = false)) {
            Snackbar.make(
                requireView(),
                "The Password and confirmation do not match", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        } else {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {

                        val action =
                            RegisterFragmentDirections.actionRegisterFragmentToMainFragment()

                        val firebaseUserID = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid



                        refUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                            .child(firebaseUserID)


                        val userHashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                        userHashMap["uid"] = firebaseUserID
                        userHashMap["username"] = userName
                        userHashMap["profile"] =
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mig33-94625.appspot.com/o/icons8-test-account-100.png?alt=media&token=ce231b05-d4a7-49cb-8003-027e0d5c76e1"
                        userHashMap["cover"] =
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mig33-94625.appspot.com/o/cover.jpg?alt=media&token=6bbcf0fb-77d1-4870-b714-aa13eedff86c"
                        userHashMap["status"] = "offline"
                        userHashMap["search"] = userName.lowercase()
                        userHashMap["facebook"] = "https://m.facebook.com"
                        userHashMap["instagram"] = "https://m.instagram.com"
                        userHashMap["website"] = "https://www.google.com"

                        refUsers.updateChildren(userHashMap).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                                Log.d("mido",refUsers.get().result.toString())
                                findNavController().navigate(action)
                            }
                        }

//
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "Error ${task.exception?.message.toString()}",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
        }

    }

}
```

**build.gradle Dependencies**

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.20"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')

    // Declare the dependency for the Realtime Database library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
```

Comment: There's too much code here. Reduce the problem set and the answer will likely be obvious: Start by trying a direct write to the DB and nothing else; no variables, no auth events, just write first. If that succeeds, try adding it back into the createUser*() call. Then try adding the variables back in. Isolate the problem first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is that you may have downloaded the `google-services.json` file before you created the Realtime Database in the console, which means that the file doesn't contain the correct configuration string.

If that is the case, you'll need to:

- either download an updated configuration file and add that to your Android app,
- or you can specify the URL for the database in the code here: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("URL to database here").reference`

If this is indeed the cause of the problem, we're working on surfacing this configuration problem more explicitly (it's currently hidden in a debug-level log message from the SDK, which isn't logged by default).

Comment: yeah that's was the problem I downloaded this file before I create the database, also after updated the file it didn't work until I specified the URL as you said like this `https://mig33-94625-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/`

Comment: Thanks for confirming @DrMido .    We're working on surfacing the error message better (it's now only logged when you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)), which is not very useful. It's weird that it still didn't work after redownloading though, so we'll keep looking if we can reproduce that too.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you haven't updated the google-services.json file, you can go to project>>app>>src>> and then either update your google services file or simply download it from firebase website,

If you don't want to do this large process then simply mention the website url of your realtime database, shown below ....

private var database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(" https://gamettt-b7471-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")

private var myRef=database.reference