# I am trying to print my data from Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch the data of a logged in user using Firebase realtime database. I am currently new to this and I hope someone can guide me. I already read the documentation but I am having this problem.

Problem is I cannot fetch the data that I needed.

Header.kt

```
private lateinit var binding: HeaderBinding
private lateinit var auth:FirebaseAuth


private lateinit var userName: TextView
private lateinit var userEmail: TextView

private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   binding = HeaderBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.header)

    database = Firebase.database.reference

    userName = findViewById(R.id.userName)
    userEmail = findViewById(R.id.userEmail)


        val userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid

        database.child("users").child(userID).get().addOnSuccessListener {

            val email = it.child("email").value.toString()
            val username = it.child("username").value.toString()

            userName.text = username
            userEmail.text =  email

        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
}
```

Header.xml

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

FIREBASE DATABASE:

[image: Firebase data image]

Comment: "I cannot fetch" is really broad, so hard to help with. Did you already set a breakpoint on `val email = it.child("email").value.toString()` and run in the debugger? If so, does it reach that breakpoint? If not, does it show the `Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` toast?

Comment: What I mean by fetch is I am just trying to get the data and print it. I tried setting a breakpoint on that val email, but it doesn't seem to reach it. It also does not generate any errors. The toast also does not appear.

Comment: In that case, most likely the client can't connect to the server. It might be worth [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and checking the log output for messages, but most likely your `google-service.json` file doesn't contain the correct URL. Redownload the file and add it to your app (again), or specify the correct URL in code: `database = Firebase.getDatabase("URL to database here")` as also shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68229892.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please also respond using @.